# Problema al comparar dos variables unicode en Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

tengo un problema al comparar dos variables unicode en python 2.7.
Lo que quiero hacer en mi programa es abrir un fichero con carácteres (especificamente son carácteres japoneses) y comparar con una serie de carácteres del mismo tipo ingresados por el usuario.

Por alguna razón el programa se salta la comparación aunque ya comprobe que se tratan del mismo tipo de variable.

Aquí dejo la porción de código con el que estoy trabajando.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    na = []
    n = open("jap.txt", "r")
    for linea in n:
            na.append(linea)
    n.close()
    ingreso = unicode(raw_input("Respuesta: "), "utf-8")
    if (ingreso == na[1]):
            print "Correcto"
    else:
            print "Incorrecto"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Primer lugar voy a suponer que tu archivo jap.txt usa UTF-8 como codificación.

El primer problema que tienes es que no eliminas los saltos de linea al leer tu txt. Para luego poder comparar con el input es necesario que sean eliminados. Una línea de tu txt se verá `"ず\n"` o `"ず\r\n"` por lo que si tu input es `"ず"`, la comparación siempre será `False`. Para ello basta con usar el método stript

Por otro lado, debes leer el archivo con la codificación adecuada para que cada elemento de tu lista de líneas sea una variable unicode con codificación UTF-8 y puedas compararla con tu input. Lo más simple es usar el módulo `codecs` de la biblioteca estándar.

El código quedaría algo asi:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

with codecs.open("jap1.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    na = [linea.strip() for linea in f]

ingreso = unicode(raw_input("Respuesta: "), 'utf-8')
if (ingreso == na[1]):
    print "Correcto"
else:
    print "Incorrecto"
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de ejecución real, a la izquierda puedes ver el contenido de *jap.txt*. En todo momento se compara la entrada con la segunda línea como haces tu (haz click sobre el gif para que se amplie):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]